# Electron giving error in asynchronous functions

Tags: node.js, electron

I am using Electron and I write this code:

```
async function fetchPage({region , role, tier}){
  return fetch(
    `https://example.com/`
  )
    .then((res) => res.text())
    .then((text) => cheerio.load(text));
}
```

```
(async() => {
 $ = await fetchPage({region: region, role: role, tier: tier});
})();
```

And i'm getting this error:

```
async function fetchPage({region , role, tier}){
      ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
```

What's wrong with this block?

Only the Electron emits errors when I try to write await/async blocks

> Solution

I started by uninstalling / removing the current electron version of my project.

```
npm uninstall electron (At the dir of the project)
npm uninstall -g electron
```

After that I installed the latest version of the electron according to the response from @jfriend00

```
npm install electron@latest --save-dev (At the dir of the project)
npm install -g electron@latest
```

Comment: Try adding `console.log(process.version)` to your script to see exactly what version of nodejs, electron is using (this is a different version than you might have installed to use nodejs by itself). My guess is that you have an old version of nodejs within electron that doesn't know about the async keyword. Otherwise, show us what code is immediately before that function declaration as there could be an error or missing semi-colon before that.

Comment: @jfriend00, the current version of the node that my electron is using is the version ``6.5.0``, how I can update this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the nodejs version that is built-in to your installed copy of electron is out of date and thus it doesn't yet support `async` and `await` in its version of nodejs.

The simplest way to update your nodejs version is to update electron as a whole with something like this:

```
npm install electron@latest
```

The current v12.0.9 version of electron should contain nodejs v14.16.